# Scene Position changing in Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I was developing an app for Hololens 1. I am having a small problem. i have three different scenes. for all scenes the position is same but on deploying to hololens, when i click a button to change scene, i think new scene is developing very near to eye and it becomes invisible. To see every new scene i have to move back every time. I need all scenes on same position which is in front of eye (35cm).
My canvas position for all scenes is (0, 0, 0.35) and camera is (0, 0, 0). Kindly suggest me a solution.
It is working fine in unity.

Comment: since the default near clipping plane is afaik 0.3 it is not unusual that you might not see anything at the beginning. Did you try to use a lower near clipping plane on the Camera (e.g. something like `0.001`)?

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for your reply. No i didn,t try. i will try with that but for every new scene or when i press button to change the scene, the upcoming scene also become invisible. to see it i have to move back also. i want all of them at same position.

Comment: And the value of clipping plan is not saving any other then 0.3. After saving it automatically changing to 0.3. Kindly guide me for that also

Comment: Are you working with the MRTK 2.0? There it is a default configuration you have to change manually.

Comment: @derHugo Yes i am using MRTK 2.1. I changed the value but on saving the scene it automatically changed again to 0.3.

Comment: As said you have to not change it on the camera but rather change it somewhere in one of the profile configurations of MoxedRealityToolkit. Don't know by memory right now but I can look it up later

Comment: See [MRTK 2 - Profile Configuration Guide](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/MixedRealityConfigurationGuide.html): Create a new MRTK profile by making a clone of `DefaultHoloLens1ConfigurationProfile` then on the Camera tab create a new Camera profile by cloning the `DefaultMixedRealityCameraProfile`. Then you should be able to adjust the clipping planes.

Comment: @derHugo Thank you so much. i will try with that.